# Display New Member Profile Picure Upon Entry

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently developing a bot for a server I'm making, and I've made the bot send a message upon user join. Everything works so far, but one detail I'm having trouble with getting to work is getting the embed to display the new member's profile picture. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I've tried adding ".displayAvatarURL", ".avatarURL", and ".avatar" to the end of "member", as well as just leaving "member" by itself, which I've previously defined as the new member of the server. This is in the line that reads ".setThumbnail(member.avatar);"

```
  var role = member.guild.roles.find("name", " Refugees ")
  member.addRole(role);
  let joinEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setDescription(`Welcome to the refuge, **${member}**! You're number **${member.guild.memberCount}** of the people to come here so far.`)
  .setColor("#fff84e")
  .setThumbnail(member.avatar);
  member.guild.channels.get("the channel's id").send(joinEmbed);

});
```

I expect the bot to send the message with the member icon displayed beneath the text in the embed, but what actually happens is the bot sends the embedded message without any image at all. The error message I get from the bot is as follows:
`(node:28936) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead`

Answer (score 0):

figured it out on my own. I was neglecting to put the term "user" in there, so where it says `member.avatar` I should be using `member.user.displayAvatarURL` instead.